# Selective Virtualization in WP7 Listbox with VirtualizingStackPanel

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-7.1, virtualization

I am referring an app like Facebook WP7 app. When we try to scroll a long list of the feed items. Only the heading of an feed item seems to be visible and when the scroll is completed remaining details gets loaded. If it is a normal Listbox where virtualization is enabled complete data disappears and all the controls seem to be recycled. So in facebook app, I thought that the virtualization is happening on selective items. Am I right?

If yes, how to do a selective virtualization? and if I am wrong what is the app exactly doing? Any resource regarding this will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just found this for something I'm working on -- sound's similar to your question: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/10/12/procrastination-ftw-lazylistbox-should-improve-your-scrolling-performance-and-responsiveness.aspx

Comment: @willmel Have read it partially, It seems to have very important info. Thanks. Will get back after completing it.

Comment: @willmel Thank you so much dude, this is the one. I am experimenting on how virtualization is happening. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is just how their data binding works.

They get an initial list that contains the "headers" and some basic information, which they show. They then make more calls to grab the rest of the info. When that info comes in, it updates in the view model and thru databinding shows up on the list.

I have apps that do that, and they behave similarly to how FB's listbox behaves.

Comment: No, you have taken me wrong. The case I described has downloaded the whole data, And the data is being invisible during scrolling. Check the link Willmel has given. It is a bit more similar to what I was asking.

Comment: And how can you expect Facebook app to be like that. I feel that to be a bad design, downloading headings and contents at different times. :)

Comment: Why bad design? In some cases, you have no choice (unless you are willing to start forming gnarly batch requests with dependant parts). In other cases, it's more important to show pepple the headers, and getting the details (more data) later on is fine - since you want to have the app feel snappy. Even Windows Explorer does that, for example, when it shows files. Extended properties are fetched after the window is populated. It's pretty standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As Willmell pointed out, this msdn [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/10/12/procrastination-ftw-lazylistbox-should-improve-your-scrolling-performance-and-responsiveness.aspx) describes what Facebook is doing exactly. The template of the listBoxItem will be switched while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/04/06/wp7-how-to-extend-listbox-when-reaching-last-item.aspx). This guide helps me to solve a similar problem.